# Roslyn and error messages

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am building a Roslyn syntax tree from my own DSL. I would like to annotate the tree with information about the original file and line where the data came from, and then to get the potential errors when validating the tree.

How would I annotate the syntax tree?

Comment: Is that info not already there?

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your tree?  I don't think you can add metadata to the trees directly...  How about adding comments to it?

```
var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public string Biz()
        {
            return ""Baz"";
        }
    }
}");
var annotatedTree = SyntaxTree.Create(tree.GetRoot()
    .WithLeadingTrivia(
        Syntax.Comment(String.Format("// source: scratch")),
        Syntax.Comment(String.Format("// date: {0}", DateTime.Now))
    )
    .NormalizeWhitespace()
);
```

Comment: As a last resort, it might work, but I would prefer to modify the metadata directly if possible. This would still be a pain, especially considering that I would need to attach comments to every line _in connection with the  original source_.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you mentioned line numbers. The `#line` directive will definitely help.